# Bounds on the Neighborhood Size of a Random Vertex in $G(n,p)$

Tags: probability, random-graphs

Let $G(n,p)$ be the Erdős-Rényi random graph model. I am interested in the regime $p = c/n$, where $c > 0$. Further, let $B_G(d)$ denote the neighborhood of depth $d$ of a randomly chosen vertex $u$ (i.e., the graph induced by all vertices with distance at most $d$ from $u$). Is it possible to obtain good upper bounds on the probability that the neighborhood size $|B_G(d)|$ exceeds a certain value? So far, I tried the following. The expected neighborhood size should be less than that of a Branching process with Poisson$(c )$ offspring distribution, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[|B_G(d)|] \leq c^{d+1}$. Then, I can say that, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $t$, such that $\mathbb{P}(|B_G(d)| \geq t) \leq \epsilon$. Does this make sense and is it possible to obtain better bounds? Is it possible to say for example that for any fixed $t$ the probability goes to zero as $n \to \infty$? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens as $n \to \infty$ is that for any fixed $d$, the $d$-neighbourhood of $u$ is almost surely a tree, and the distribution approaches that for the Poisson branching process.  This will not be $0$ for any fixed $t$.

EDIT: If the offspring distribution for a branching process has probability generating function $\phi(s) = E[s^Y]$ (where $Y$ is the number of offspring of an individual), then the probability generating function
for the size $X_n$ of $n$'th generation (with $X_0 = 1$) is $\phi_n(s)$ where
$\phi_0(s) = 1$ and $\phi_{n+1}(s) = \phi_n(\phi(s))$, i.e. $\phi_n$ is the 
$n$-fold iterate of $\phi$.

If $Y$ has mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then
the mean and standard deviation of $X_n$ are $\mu_n$ and $\sigma_n$ where
$\mu_n = \phi_n'(1) = \mu^n$, while if I'm not mistaken
$$\sigma_n^2  = \sigma^2 \dfrac{\mu^k - \mu^{2k}}{\mu - \mu^2} = \sigma^2 \mu^{k-1}(1 + \mu + \ldots + \mu^{k-1})$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if the above bound with Markov's inequality can be improved? For example for branching processes, is it possible to get the variance of the size of the process up to a certain depth?